# Plot grouped bar chart for categorical data

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

I have a python dataframe with 10 columns. 2 of the columns (A and B) look like this:

```
A   B
y   n
y   y
y   nn
y   n
nn  y
n   nn
n   y
n   n
n   y
y   n
n   nn
```

I need to plot a grouped bar chart. The x-axis should have y, n and nn. The y-axis should have the counts of these three. I am not sure how to do this in case of categorical data. The empty rows for each column are different. Column A had 539 values and Column B has 480.

Any leads are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `pandas` you can `apply` the method `value_counts` to each column then plot results:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: How should I provide both column names in the above mentioned code? @Mykola Zotko

Comment: You can select columns df[["A", "B"]].

Comment: I am trying to do it this way: df[["A", "B"]].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).plot.bar(), but I get KeyError: ('A', 'B')

Answer (score 0):

You can also use seaborn on a melted data frame, but there might be something odd about your data frame such that the answer by @Mykola doesn't work:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.countplot(x='value',hue='variable',data=df.melt())
```

[image]